# does sql's rowversioning also prevent non repetable/phantom reads?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I understand isolation levels : `read uncommited, commited, repeatable reads, serializable.`

The thing is that I want to make sure in my app, I don't have `lost/update` problem.

**Question 1)** So as I have read, none of the isolation levels I posted above solves that problem. Is that right?

**Question 2)** As none of them solves that and also repeatable reads cause deadlocks sometimes, I am going to use rowversioning of sql. Now, as it's optimistic concurrency, and this also solves **lost/update** problem, **I am sure in this way, non-repeatable, dirty reads  will happen**, because we don't use those isolation levels I posted above. Is that right?

**Question 3)** So it means, I can't have everything as it's kind of trade-off and i have to choose one way over another?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: the idea is the same and one comes from the previous. that's why I posted it this way.

Comment: Hi, could you check and [edit] the tags on this question? You've tagged both MySQL and SQL Server, but these are different products, so you should only tag the one you're using. Also, mysqli is a PHP library, so probably irrelevant to the question. It might also help to clarify what you mean by "lost/update problem".